# Selenium IDE "Tab not found' although it is open

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE to automate some browser processes, I need to do a test from which I open the source code of a page (view-source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeQuelXsUYA) and trying to find a certain word, I am using youtube as an example, however when clicking on "Select target in page" the following error appears "Tab not found / No guide is available for this test case, please keep recording or play. " I've tested it with several pages, and command recording works fine, but every time I open the page's source code, the selenium IDE doesn't record the commands.

Thanks in advance.

[![This is the image of the error, the first script I ask to open the page's source code works, however when I try to select target in page, the error appears, as if the page were not open.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8ezU.png)

Comment: What programming language you are using? And why you are writing tests in selenium IDE?

Comment: I'm new to the world of programming and I'm trying to automate some tasks I do in the browser, that's why I use the selenium IDE because it allows recording of commands, the program recognizes all other pages, but when I enter the source code of the page, the program does not recognize.

Comment: What program? IDE should log the code that is being executed. Add more details to the question.

Comment: I've added more details of my problem, and from my testing it seems to be a selenium IDE bug, as it just doesn't work when I open the source code, if anyone knows a way around it.